# How do I get Russian characters from SQL statement to come through JSON correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, content-type

Using MyPHP

I have managed to get the SQL database to store Russian characters, using `utf8_unicode_ci`

PHP Header is set as: `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`

The database call is set with: `mysql_set_charset("utf8", $reference);`

In the database there is an entry as `наперстянка` but in the JSON response it displays as `Ð½Ð°Ð¿ÐµÑ€ÑÑ‚ÑÐ½Ðº`

After a ton of research tonight, I can't seem to find anything that will fix this issue.

Comment: may be its encoded in the browser, how you view it? you need to set charset=utf-8 for the file where you display it... for example: view.php

Comment: utf8encode the response?

Comment: What is the DDL for the table in question? Interested for anything related to encoding

Comment: so the header is on the php that is requested - not using it in a browser, it's for localising an iOS application - I am testing in the application & in a Rested client - both with the same results

Comment: I am currently running through this guide http://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql hopefully there is something simple that I have missed out.

Comment: Still not had any luck, the only thing from that guide I can't seem to do is the my.ini cause it's not available.